# Datanucleus with mongodb geospatial - how?

Tags: mongodb, jpa, datanucleus

I use Datanucleus JPA with mongodb - It's ok. But now I need to use geospatial queries. I know how make this queries with mongo's java native driver. How can I mix native mongo java driver with JPA or maybe another more propper solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MongoDB Java driver is not compatible with JPA, as JPA was designed for relational databases and MongoDB is a NoSQL document database.

However, you could take a look at [Morphia](https://github.com/mongodb/morphia), which is a lightweight ODM (Object Document Mapper) which will turn Java objects into MongoDB documents and vice versa.  There's also some support for geospatial queries in there too.

Comment: Datanucleus JPA works with mongodb! But I will use morphia, because i need geospatial support.

Comment: Note I didn't say it doesn't work with Datanucleus, just that JPA is designed for relational databases not document databases like MongoDB. I'm glad to see it does work, but the JPA spec is not a good natural fit for MongoDB.

Answer (score 3):

DataNucleus JPA clearly works with MongoDB, so the other answer is erroneous in that respect.

Perhaps the other answer meant to say that certain parts of the JPA spec (particularly JPQL) are targetted totally towards RDBMS, so can be non-optimal for MongoDB. But then if saying that the poster could also say that JDO **is** targetted to ALL types of datastores, and it's query language would be suitable for what you require (and allows geospatial functions for RDBMS so could fit what you require in principle).

In answering the specific question, I don't think DataNucleus has explicit support for the geospatial functions of MongoDB, but they have plugin points so you could write something easily enough that extends their current query mechanism. The other alternative is that DataNucleus provides access to the "DB" object being used, so you could take that and do your native query, and then hand the "DB" back to DataNucleus when done.